# Is there a new skeleton for framebuffer in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

I found that you redesign this skeleton on 2001:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/skeletonfb.c

Does it still hold? or there are any new guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never been writing framebuffer device drivers for Linux, but I would suggest you just compile and run it. If it works, apparently it is not outdated ;)